# Swift Package Manager fetches dependencies each time Xcode is opened

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, swift-package-manager

i have a couple projects that have SPM integrated in them. SPM fetches dependencies without any problems, but the most annoying thing is that it fetches them every time i close and reopen Xcode. This wouldn't have been an issue if there weren't many dependencies, but unfortunately that is not the case. Is there a way to alter this behaviour and make SPM not fetch packages each time i open a project?

Comment: Is `Package.resolved` under source control? is it changed when you opening xcode? do you check it in _if_ it changes?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply clone the packages locally and point to the local packages, this will also be very quick to open Xcode projects since there are no need to fetch any thing.

I do this with my projects as I code a lot while travelling and in airplanes and this works with me since I can't work if Xcode will try to fetch while there is no internet in the sky!

You can also write small piece of shell script code to automate updating your local packages if you want thou..

Comment: how can we do that

Comment: @cs4alhaider could you please share how to achieve this ?